# Is "multistage rounding" of fractional numbers a thing?

Tags: rounding-error, rounding

**Problem:**

Due to precision errors I get a number, say, `0.004999999999`. Mathematically speaking `0.00499(9)` equals `0.005` *precisely*, but not in computers.

Such level of precision is still fine, but when I display the number, the user expects to see `0.01`, i.e. rounded to two decimal points, but obviously any sane rounding algorithm would return `0.00` instead since `0.004999999999` is definitely closer to `0.00` than to `0.01`.

But the user understanably expects to see `0.01`

**Solution(?):**

It can be done with "multistage rounding" like `0.004999999999.round(10).round(2)` given we internally calculate everything to a precision of `10` decimal points.

It seems to be a very common problem, but I surprisingly couldn't find any conventional solution to it.

Comment: No, the double rounding won't work, because even with 10 decimal digits you can't get closer to 0.005. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987). Oops, bad example, that specific number rounds up instead of down. But there are certainly numbers that won't.

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes, I know about floating point math problems. This question is not related to floating point arithmetics as the same can happen even with decimal numbers. Also `0.004999999999.round(10).round(2)` returns `0.01` as expected, it works but just does not seem right

Comment: So you're saying you were given a *decimal* number of `0.004999999999` as input? Why then would you expect it to round to `0.01`?

Comment: Becasue it should have been `0.005` but even decimal number hit a limit at some point, `1.to_decimal / 3 * 3` => `0.999999999999999999`

Comment: I think the reason you don't see more relating to this problem is that you're the only one who assumes trailing decimal 9's must be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the double rounding approach, just be aware that binary numbers can't exactly represent decimals so sometimes the results aren't what you expect. Your example works in Python but another very similar one does not:

```
>>> round(round(0.004999999999, 10), 2)
0.01
>>> round(round(0.044999999999, 10), 2)
0.04
```

In the first case the first rounding produces a number just *over* 0.005 while the second produces a number just *under* 0.045; the exact numbers are 0.005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875 and 0.04499999999999999833466546306226518936455249786376953125. Nothing closer is possible using binary numbers. If your language has a decimal number system, you could use that to get consistent results by avoiding the conversion to binary.

An alternate approach is to multiply the number by a very small amount so that something close to the boundary gets pushed over it.

```
>>> round(0.004999999999 * 1.000000001, 2)
0.01
>>> round(0.044999999999 * 1.000000001, 2)
0.05
```

Again, this approach won't work for every number, but it prioritizes the case you care about - you're more likely to get numbers rounded up when they should be rounded down.